# Read from a file and display the total number of items as Integer

Tags: java

I'm a beginner, this is very basic stuff. I have a plain text file filled with ice cream flavors. I need to, at the end of the program:

1- Print out the total number of items

2- Print out how many "Strawberry" flavors occurred

I've been trying all day and I've no idea what to do anymore. My counters don't add properly and stay always at 1.

```
public class IceCream {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here


    TextIO.readFile("src\\icecream\\icecream.txt");

    while (TextIO.eof() == false) {
        String cones;
        int totalCones = 0;
        cones = TextIO.getln();
        TextIO.putln(cones);
        totalCones++;
        if (cones.equals("Strawberry")) {
            int strawberryCones = 0;
            strawberryCones++;
            if (TextIO.eof() == true) {
                TextIO.putln(strawberryCones);
            }
        }
        if (TextIO.eof() == true) {
            TextIO.putln(totalCones);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Declare the counters outside (before) the loops. Right now, you declare a variable, assign it the value zero, then add 1.

Comment: Can you provide at least some snippet of a text file you are using?

Comment: Also, don't use `TextIO.eof() == true` or `TextIO.eof() == false`: use `TextIO.eof()` or `!TextIO.eof()` respectively.

Comment: What is the definition of `TextIO` class. Also What is the content of _icecream.txt_ file?

Comment: Andy Turner. Thanks, it worked. I just needed to declare the variables outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works what you have asked it to. You're asking it to reset the counter to zero, each time it finds a "strawberry". So, no matter how many "strawberry"s, you have in the file, it ends up, printing 1.

The line "int strawberryCones = 0" must go above the if block.
Cheers!

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. Still display just "1". Edit: It worked, I needed to declare the variables outside the while loop.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice the while loop!